# Change background color of histogram according to a percentage

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have a histogram and I would like to color the background between 16.5% and 83.5% of points that are distributed in the histogram.

How can I do that? How to find these points?

The data are in `file` - one column of values.

```
h = histogram( file, 50 );
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just like to add another variant. Using the histogram properties and prctile to find the limits:

```
data = randn(100000,1);

% Start with the original histogram
figure;
h=histogram(data,50);
% Find the bin edges you received.
be=h.BinEdges;

% Find the limits where your percentile limits lie
y=prctile(data,[16.5 83.5]);

% However, percentile limits will not generally concide with your bin-limits, so this must be fudged.

% Option A: Adjust be, to lie on the percentiles.
% DYI

% Option B: Adjust your limits for a pretty plot

% Find which be indicies are closest to the desired limits.
vals=y(:); 
rv=be(:)';
diffs=bsxfun(@minus,vals, rv); % Finds differences to all be for all vals.
[~,inds]=min(abs(diffs),[],2); % Finds the minimum ones.
vals=rv(inds);                 % Find values to use for the cutoff.

% Replace the original plot with the inner cut.
h1=histogram(data(data>vals(1) & data<vals(2)),'BinEdges',be);
hold on;
% Plot the data outside the limits.
h2=histogram(data(data<vals(1) | data>vals(2)),'BinEdges',be);

% Pretty colors have ensued. As per post, you can color the tails to
% something else
h2.FaceColor='white';
```

[image: Colored Histogram]

Due credit to Tom R for rounding to specific values:
https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37674-roundtowardvec

Comment: Very nice answer

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Thank you, I appreciate that!

Comment: Thank you very much and what does vals mean?

Comment: vals is just short for the "values" that are rounded to the bin limits required. About the ax=gca; ax.FontSize=12; that worked fine for me (R2016b version). Check that you got the correct axis loaded into ax.

Comment: Nice result, worth noting that `prctile` is dependant on the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox.

Comment: Thanks! Agree, your cumsum approach is probably more to the point on finding the edges in a histplot - and less license demanding.

Comment: Why is what is the defference in rv and be? They are not transposed vectors?

Comment: rv and vals must be on different dimensions (one row vector and one column vector) to make the  [bsxfun](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) expand all combinations for which the difference between them are taken.

Answer (score 5):

Please see the code comments for details, basically you can use `patch` to highlight the background, and some logical indexing to find which bins fall within your 16.5% - 83.5% threshold.

This uses `bar` and `histcounts` to create the histogram rather than `histogram`, as you get more useful outputs and we want intermediary steps before plotting.

```
rng(0); % for repeatable random numbers
x = normrnd( 0, 1, 1000, 1 ) * 10; % Create data

% Get the histogram counts with 50 bins
[hc, edges] = histcounts( x, 50 );

% Lower and upper bounds we're interested in highlighting
region = [0.165, 0.835];
% Cumulative percentage across the bins
pct = cumsum( hc ) / sum( hc );
% Index to get which meet our bounds
idx = pct >= region(1) & pct <= region(2);

% Set up the plot
x = (edges(1:end-1)+edges(2:end))/2;
maxY = 1.1*max(hc);
n = nnz(idx);

% Plot
figure; hold on
patch( [x(idx),fliplr(x(idx))], [zeros(1,n),ones(1,n)]*maxY, 'y', 'edgecolor', 'none' );
bar( x, hc );
hold off
ylim( [0, maxY] );
```

Result:

[image: hist]